# How to avoid System.Xml.Linq.XElement escaping HTML content?

Tags: asp.net, html, escaping, xelement

I'm using the XElement object to build some HTML in the code-behind on an ASP.NET page.

I may or may not add some XAttributes to this XElement as I go along, in the following fashion:

```
var elmnt = new XElement("div",
     new XAttribute("id", "myDiv"),
     );
```

Now, if I want to add some content into *myDiv* which contains HTML, the XElement automatically escapes this which, in my situation, is undesirable.

So if I have:

```
var elmnt = new XElement("div",
     new XAttribute("id", "myDiv"),
     "<span id='content'>hello world</span>"
     );
```

And then I render this into a Placeholder object using the following code:

```
myPlaceholder.Controls.Add(new System.Web.UI.WebControls.Literal { Text = elmnt.CreateNavigator().OuterXml });
```

When the page loads, the source reveals that the inner content inside *elmnt* has been escaped, and has the following format in the page's source:

```
&lt;span id='content'&gt;hello world&lt;/span&gt;
```

Given that the XML I'm compiling here is valid HTML, and the inner content is also valid HTML, how can I tell the XElement parent object to *not* escape the inner content? How can I leave it in its native format?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
 var elmnt = new XElement("div",
   new XAttribute("id", "myDiv"),
   new XRaw("<span id='content'>hello world</span>")
 );


public class XRaw : XText
{
  public XRaw(string text):base(text){}
  public XRaw(XText text): base(text){}

  public override void WriteTo(System.Xml.XmlWriter writer)
  {
    writer.WriteRaw(this.Value);
  }
}
```

Comment: This will not handle adding an XElement value as XRaw with a Boolean value or an object like XElement does. You can add this to the constructor to handle most cases: public XRaw(object text) : base(text?.ToString()) { }

Answer (score 0):

If you are treating the HTML as XML then when you add to it you have to add XML

Thus you would make a new xmlelement (span), add an attribute (for attribute id, value content) and then set it's contents to "hello world".  Take this xmlelement and add it to the tree in the right spot.

All of this seems to be heading in the wrong direction to me.  If you want to be able to have "dynamic" content in the code behind I would suggest: adding a `asp:label` or `aps:placeholder` control to the page and then setting the content of that control to the html in the code behind.  This is the standard way of adding dynamic content.

Comment: The reason I'm building the content this way is that I want to cache elements of the page - for this to happen these elements must be serializable. The content inside the XElement is coming from an HTML field in a CMS.
I hope that explains to all readers of my question why I'm looking to achieve a result using the XElement to contain HTML.

Comment: @awj - nothing wrong with that.  An `asp:placeholder` could handle a string from your database just fine.  Nothing is more serializable than a string.

Comment: @awj - actually a `asp:literalcontrol` or `asp:label` is probably what you want.  Do you want me to post an example of how to use it?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by using the HtmlAgilitypack to convert the string of HTML into a hierarchical object.

I then looped through each HTML element in this object and created a nested XElement for each.

There's a little bit of checking that needs done on every element, but it works perfectly and has fewer lines of code than I expected when I started building it.

Answer (score -1):

Why wouldn't you use [HtmlTextWriter?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmltextwriter.aspx)

```
StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();

HtmlTextWriter htmlWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWriter);
htmlWriter.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Span);
htmlWriter.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Id, "content");
htmlWriter.Write("hello world");
htmlWriter.RenderEndTag();

htmlWriter.Flush();

stringWriter.ToString(); //<span id='content'>hello world</span>
```

Comment: the HtmlTextWriter class is marked as `MustInherit`, so with my limited knowledge I'm not sure how best to implement an HtmlTextWriter into my XElement object. I know it's a big ask but could you provide a short example of how I'd convert (using my above example) `<span id='content'>hello world</span>` into an HtmlTextWriter object?

Comment: I should also mention that I'm keen to use the XElement class because I'm using a bespoke cache that accepts XElements, but I'm not sure if it will accept an instance of an HtmlTextWriter.
Also, are you suggesting that I replace the entire XElement with an HtmlTextWriter rather than using this to simply contain the inner HTML?

Comment: @awj see my updated post about usage. I dont understand what MustInherit you are talking about, but anyways, this class is public and already implemented.I suggest that for building html, HtmlTextWriter is much more simpler and powerfull than XElement. XElement is more general

Comment: Please see my comment below the next post as to why I want to use the XElement, although I very much appreciate the example. The HtmlTextWriter would be suitable if I simply wanted to concatenate HTML elements, but like I write below, I want to cache the object (XElement is serializable) and the inner content - containing the HTML - is coming out of a CMS.