# Including js file in XHTML with XElement

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, xml

I have a problem with including a js file from resources into my generated XHTML file, I always did it this way:

```
new XElement("SCRIPT", new XAttribute("language", "javascript"), new XAttribute("type", "text/javascript"), "\n" + MyResources.jsFile + "\n");
```

same for CSS and it was always fine but now my js file includes '<' and '>' characters and they are changed into &lt and &gt after saving what destroys my entire  function, can I somehow avoid that? 
I'd prefer to stay with XElements if it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Use [XCData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xcdata.aspx) Node

```
new XCData(MyResources.jsFile)
```

Text inside a `CDATA` section will be ignored by the parser.

---

You cant use XElement since it would escape the `<`,`>`,`&` symbols

Comment: Yeah but when it is inside CData the script won't run :( .

Comment: @AndrzejCzerwoniec don't assume it! Even [facebook](http://www.facebook.com) has its javascipt embedded inside `<![CDATA`

Comment: I've just tried it out on the easiest example and it doesn't seem to work for me:
     <SCRIPT language="javascript" type="text/javascript"><![CDATA[ alert("HELLO"); ]]></SCRIPT>
doesn't display the alert :/ .

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have fixed the problem by using a class derived from XText like it was done here:
[How to avoid System.Xml.Linq.XElement escaping HTML content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5613978/how-to-avoid-system-xml-linq-xelement-escaping-html-content)

```
 public class XRaw : XText
 {
      public XRaw(string text):base(text){}
      public XRaw(XText text): base(text){}

      public override void WriteTo(System.Xml.XmlWriter writer)
      {
           writer.WriteRaw(this.Value);
      }
 }
```