# &amp; in XElement

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I want to generate `<element>&amp;</element>` using `System.Xml.Linq.XElement`.

I tried this: `new XElement("element", "&amp;")` but it escapes the ampersand and it generates: `<element>&amp;amp;</element>`

The only workaround I can think of is to create a custom class that inherits from `XText`, override the `WriteTo` method and use the `XmlWriter` => `WriteEntityRef` method. It seems to me that this is a bit of an overkill. Is there another way of doing this?

Comment: What about "\u00a0"?

Comment: That outputs: `<span> </span>`...

Comment: @LeonardoSeccia is that not what you want?

Comment: Also, are you trying to make XML into HTML?  That wont work, HTML is _not_ XML

Comment: Isn't it correct that the `&` is escaped in the XML? If you want to use it as html later on, you can unescape it there (will probably be done by the XML reader at that point). I don't think you should put the `&` in the XML because it will create invalid XML

Comment: I have replaced the `&nbsp;` to `&amp;` and `span` to `element` to avoid any further feedback about html not being xml, etc.

Comment: @Stefan this is not duplicate as it is not so much about Xml escape characters but about `XElement`

Comment: Just use `new XElement("element", "&")`. Note that your title doesn't match your body. You're trying to create `&amp;`, not `&nsbp;`

Comment: (Basically, let LINQ to XML do the escaping for you - logically you're trying to create an element with text of a single ampersand.)

Comment: @maccettura `XHTML` is part of the family of XML markup languages, in other words an application of `XML`.

Comment: @LeonardoSeccia they are still different enough where using XElements is a bad idea. If you need to build an HTML structure in code then you absolutely will be better off using a specialized library like [HtmlAgilityPack](http://html-agility-pack.net/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in the comments and in the answer `new XElement("element", "&")` will actually leverage on the framework to escape the ampersand correctly.

Part of the issue I had with this was the fact that initially I was trying to put `&nbsp;` in my xml element with no much success. I was unaware that unless my XML has a DTD which defines `&nbsp;`, I can't use `&nbsp;`.

Since then, I updated my question to use `&amp;` instead and this in turn changed the behaviour of `XElement` because unlike a space, `&` needs escaping in XML, and LINQ to XML does this automatically (as expected).

Comment: The `&nbsp;` entity is U00A0, the *non breaking space*. I'm pretty sure, that there would be some kind of escaping when you pass over this character. And yes, an entity must be *known* previously.

Comment: Is there a way to prevent Linq to Xml tp escape the &? I'm creating a document in which I need the output to be written "&", not "&amp". The output is not useful for my purposes if I don't get the "&" string...

Comment: @Carlos H - I think you can use `XRaw` instead... This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5613978/how-to-avoid-system-xml-linq-xelement-escaping-html-content

Answer (score 1):

You've got the solution in comment already, just some background:

You must understand the difference between the content *as is (**outside** the XML)* and its *representation **within** the XML*. Outside of the XML you see the plain content, when it is written into the XML it is escaped automatically, on reading it is re-escaped again.

> I tried this: `new XElement("element", "&amp;")` but it escapes the
>   ampersand and it generates: `<element>&amp;amp;</element>`

This shows clearly, what's going on. By passing in `&amp;` you get `&amp;amp;`. The engine sees the `&` and replaces it with the entity.

Just use `new XElement("element", "&")` which should get you the result needed.